# sequelize pass extra parameters to logging function

Tags: node.js, logging, sequelize.js

**QUESTION:** Is there any way to pass any extra information to the sequelize logging function?

**WHY I NEED THIS:**
My app requieres to log every query and get elapsed time, problem is that using sequelize built-in `benchmark: true` option only logs queries AFTER they return, I'd like to be able to log two messages per query, for example:

```
2016-12-23 16:25:57.152 QUERY #A0E92A247 Executing SELECT * FROM foo;
2016-12-23 16:25:57.177 QUERY #A0E92A247 ELAPSED 25ms
```

My current code results in something like this:

```
2016-12-23 16:25:57.152 QUERY #A0E92A247 STARTED
2016-12-23 16:25:57.153 QUERY Executing (default): SELECT * FROM foo;
2016-12-23 16:25:57.177 QUERY #A0E92A247 ELAPSED 25ms
```

Issue being that in a highly async system with several queries running concurrently it would be harder to know wich queries are getting stuck.

Comment: Did you find any solution?